# I want to "bootstrap" (read average) my regression results

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

## Question

So what I want to do is simple. I want to run a regression 10 times (or one hundred times), and somehow combine or average the outcomes. Obviously normally running a regression multiple times does not change the outcome, but for mine it does (see below).

## Background

You can use the package `sure` ([link](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2018/RJ-2018-004/RJ-2018-004.pdf#section.2.2)), to calculate surrogate residuals of a `polr` with `resids`.*
The problem is that these surrogate residuals require sampling from a continuous distribution; consequently, the result will be different with every call to resids (they don't converge from bootstrapping the residuals).

To circumvent this issue, I want kind of "bootstrap" this whole deal, until (in contrast to the residuals) perhaps the model converges (this is probably too much to ask, but lets say I want to get a good average).

## DATA

```
library(sure) # for residual function and sample data sets
library(MASS) # for polr function

df1 <- df1
df1$z1 <- df1$x
df1$x <- NULL
df1$x <- df2$y
df1$z2 <- df2$x
df1$y <- df3$x

mod1 <- polr(as.ordered(x) ~ z1 + z2, data=df1, method='probit')
df1$residuals <- resids(mod1, nsim=100, method="latent")
mod2 <- lm(y ~ x + residuals + z1 + z2, data=df1)
summary(mod2)
```

.*The package is based on [this paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/01621459.2017.1292915), in the Journal of the American Statistical Association.

Comment: From your question, "I want to run a regression 10 times (or one hundred times) and somehow combine or average the outcomes". Why not bootstrapping the entire dataset (`df1` in your example) to run your regression with different sets of data and then simply average each model's prediction?

Comment: Thank you for your comment Elia. I considered that. But my dataset is quite large (I would probably run out of memory). and it's really only the residual that changes. I kind of hoped there would be a package to do this.

Comment: I guess I could just add 100 residuals to the data. And then loop through them. Still I was hoping for something cleaner (and more efficient) , which also properly computes all coefficients, so that I don't make any mistakes.

Comment: Hi again! :) 
I think this might actually be more of a question for cross-validated. E.g. [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/167440/bootstrapped-coefficients-for-ordinal-logistic-regression-with-r ) user wanted to bootstrap his ordinal logistic reg as well, only he was using orm(). I am not sure though, why you want to bootstrap the residuals, since they are already bootstrapped? And from the paper I understand that the residuals are only for diagnostic purposed, so you only need to look at them once for the asumptions . Then you can probably safely bootstrap coefficients?

Comment: @Datapumpernickel Thank you very much for your comment! I actually had a related question on CV as well (but I didn't see this one, so thank you!) . I'll see if I can tinker with the code. The problem with the residuals is that I get quite some variation in my estimates. And because the residuals doesn't converge, the estimate doesn't converge. I'm more trying to "bootstrap" the estimate rather than the se and ci.

Comment: Hmm. Since no one else is giving any insight, my next (maybe stupid) question would be: Why are you using these surrogate residuals for another linear regression? Maybe somebody can help, if you explain why you want to calculate a regression on residuals that are for diagnostic purposes?

Comment: @Datapumpernickel Not a stupid question at all. This is the background: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/519852/how-to-do-a-control-function-cf-two-stage-residual-inclusion-2sri-with-an. I'm trying to estimate a two stage model with an ordinal first and a nonlinear second..

Comment: I'm trying to somehow estimate this model consistently, but I'm not having much luck haha

Comment: @Tom Uff. Ok. Sorry to hear that. Now I am understanding the complexity of what you are asking... No idea...

Comment: @Tom ok, last attempt. You might have thought about that already, but why not use SBS residuals? See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PResiduals/index.html They are even mentioned in the paper on surrogate residuals. Simply "inconvenient" for diagnostic because they are discrete, but maybe helpful for you? https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2018/RJ-2018-004/RJ-2018-004.pdf Maybe send the authors an old-fashioned email?

Comment: @Datapumpernickel Thank you so much for pointing that out! I cannot believe I missed that. After I read inconvenient, and did not see a package (even though there was one: `PResiduals`), I kind of moved on to surrogate and forgot about it.

Comment: @Datapumpernickel I'm getting stable results now. Thank you so much for your time and patience!

Comment: @Tom I am glad it helped! However, I think you will have to justify, whether residuals from an ordered probit are even fit to be used with a two-stage regression in the way you are using them - besides of the fact that they are stable. However, that is more of a cross-validated question again I think. Or like I previously suggested, maybe emailing some relevant faculty/academics that worked on this.